# Leibniz chain rule for derivatives of integral functions

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I'm studying some topics on PDE and I'm having trouble with a really basic thing... how embarrassing!

I'm trying to compute the following derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(t,x)$$
where $$u(t,x)=\phi(x-ct)+\int_0^tf(s,x-ct+cs)ds$$
My answer was $$\frac{d}{dt}u(t,x)=-c\phi'(x+ct)+f(t,x)+\int_0^t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(s,x-ct+cs)ds$$
However, my professor wrote:$$\frac{d}{dt}u(t,x)=-c\phi'(x+ct)+f(t,x)+-c\int_0^t\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(s,x-ct+cs)ds$$
I was wondering: does the following hold? $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(s,x-ct+cs)=-c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(s,x-ct+cs)$$
My guess was that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(s,g(x,t,s))=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}f(s,g(x,t,s))\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(s)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = 0+(-c)\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}
$$ but I don't see how this could help... can someone help me, please?

Comment: You must distinguish between
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(s,g(x,t,s)$$
(the derivative of $t\mapsto f(s,g(x,t,s)$) and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,g(x,t,s))$$
(the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its second variable, arbitrarily denoted by $x$, evaluated at $(s,g(x,t,s)).$ (Note the distinct positions of $f$ in these two expressions.) With that meaning, the chain rule gives:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(s,g(x,t,s))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,g(x,t,s))\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x,t,s).$$

Comment: The dispute is only about the term
$$
\int_0^t\frac{d}{dt}f(s,x-ct+cs)\,ds\,.
$$
You should not use a partial derivative here. When you apply now the chain rule you will see that your professor was correct.

Comment: @KurtG. I find the notation a bit confusing… why is the partial differential symbol used here? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @AnneBauval I see… but is it correct to call $x$ both the second term of $f$ and one of the therms of $g$?

Comment: A better notation would probably be $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(s,x-ct+cs)=-c\,\color{red}{\partial_2}f(s,x-ct+cs)\,.$$ Or $$\frac{d}{d t}f(s,x-ct+cs)=-c\,\color{red}{\partial_2}f(s,x-ct+cs)\,.$$ (The disambiguation on the RHS is more important than how we write the LHS.)